# Start Docker Desktop automatically after Windows Server restart

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2022 with Docker Desktop installed.

I am trying to make Docker always start after the server restarts.
I tried to set the Docker service from manual to auto, but after restart the service is set back to manual and does not start.

Finally I created a scheduled task that starts Docker Desktop after startup independent from a login. That technically works, but has a weird side effect:

When I'm logged in, Docker Desktop is not visually started and if I try to open it, it's doing nothing. Even when I type `docker ps` it's not responding and loading forever.

Answer (score 3):

Docker Desktop is not meant to be used on servers (hence the name `Desktop`). Microsoft has extensive documentation on how to install Docker on a Windows Server properly.

Use a supported configuration and you won't have such problems.

Comment: Just a hint and not a real solution. You mean I should use WSL for example?

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to find the documentation. Its too extensive to copy and paste here and we don't provide links to external resources here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the setting `Start Docker Desktop when you log in`?

This is located in the `Settings` in the `General` Tab.

Guess this could also be set directly in the settings file:

```
%Appdata%\Docker\settings.json
```

Comment: Sure but after a Reboot, I am not logging in